# Oграничение доступа (htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте!

Есть вопрос по поводу ограничения доступа.

Нужно что бы доступ извне к сайту был запрещен(знаю как сделать), если человек пытается зайти напрямую, но если запрос происходит через api, то ограничение не применяется.

Нужно ограничить доступ к crm системе.

Буду благодарен если подскажете либо как сделать , либо где искать .
Спасибо!

Comment: Чем у вас отличаются запросы через api, от запросов к страницам сайта?

Comment: @Visman, суть в том что бы ограничить доступ к сайту по ip, если запрос на api будет исходить с другого ip то он не пройдет, а нужно что бы htaccess этот запрос пропустил. 
Есть идея что бы прописать правило, по которому будет проверка хоста по которому идет запрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте так

```
# 1 этап
#запрещаем, например, доступ к файлам с раширением .php для всех, кроме
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  # первый ip, которому разрешен доступ
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
  # второй  ip, которому разрешен доступ
  Allow from ::1
  # и так далее
</FilesMatch>

# 2 этап
# разрешаем доступ к api (тут в регулярке указан файл "api.php") для всех
<FilesMatch "^api\.php$">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Вам только останется указать список ip с которых доступ к сайту разрешен и имя файла в виде регулярного выражение на котором у вас доступ к api висит.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку !
Учту, но остается еще один момент , как я указывал, запрещается доступ к crm, а где там лежит файл с апи(и не разбит ли он на части), я не знаю. Если не будет других вариантов и идей буду пробовать на примере вашей инструкции.

Comment: @BogdanGudyma, регуляркой можно указать не один файл, а множество, но достаточно разрешить доступ только к тому, который является "входом"  в api, а те файлы, которые подключаются через include/require в нем, будут запускаться без проблем.